# Does a MacBook need to be plugged in to install OS X?

Tags: macos, installation, macbook

I want to install OS X to my Macbook. Do I have to have my Macbook plugged into the mains power during the install or can I do this while on the battery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically - No - as long as there is enough battery power for the time required to install OSX.  It is recommended to be plugged in though.

Comment: Thanks. Can you help me with more Mac woes? here: http://superuser.com/questions/90540/help-setting-up-borrowed-boot-camp-mac